# Filter ifnumgreater not working with csvsimple

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, csvsimple, filter

LaTeX gives me an error every time I add the line containing the filter. It works fine without the filter. What have I done wrong?

Here is my LaTeX entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}  %spacing between lines of a same paragraph
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}           %set margins
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents,longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{random.csv}
A,  B,  C
egfwgt, 36, ery
wrgsreh,    3645467,    yfghs
rshgtesh,   346,    rsth
ethshs, 365,    sty
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{table}[H]
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.2in}
        \begin{center}
        \csvreader 
            [tabular=ccc,
            table head= \toprule A & B & C \\ \midrule,
            table foot= \bottomrule, 
            filter test=\ifnumgreater{\B}{300},
            ]%
            {random.csv}{A=\A, B=\B, C=\C}%
            {\A  & \B & \C}
        \end{center} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is on a csv file, I just wanted to show what was on it. It's really the filter that's the problem since it works fine when I add a '%' in front of my filter. the error given is 'package pgfkeys Error'. Thank you for your quick answer, I am very new to LaTex :)

Comment: Have you tried `full filter={\ifnum\B>300\csvfilteraccept\else\csvfilterreject\fi}` too?

Answer (score 3):

As you probably already noticed the input has to be comma separated values, thus now the input is correct. Next look at page 18 in the manual, it has an example that makes this work, resulting in using

```
full filter= \ifnumgreater{\B}{300}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject},
```

According to the manual `filter=...` is the same as `filter ifthen=...` and thus only constructions from the `ifthen`package are viable.

For reference here is my complete, working example, with irrelevant (for this question) stuff removed (running on texlive 2016)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents,longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{random.csv}
A,B,C
egfwgt,36,ery
wrgsreh,3645467,yfghs
rshgtesh,346,rsth
ethshs,365,sty
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}


            \csvreader 
                [tabular=ccc,
                table head= \toprule A & B & C \\ \midrule,
                late after line= \\,
                table foot= \bottomrule, %very important to put line at bottom
                full filter= \ifnumgreater{\B}{300}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject},
                ]%
                {random.csv}{A=\A, B=\B, C=\C}%
                {\A  & \B & \C}



\end{document}
```

---

BTW please don't use the `float` package and the [H] option for floats, better learn to use floats properly.

Comment: hi! The code you gave is working on my coworkers computer (a Window), but not on my Mac. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: @ValerieDesjardins versions! Which latex installation and version are you running on your mac? It is usually listed at the top of the log file that latex creates when you compile.

Comment: Mine is listing `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.3.7)  2 MAY 2017 22:25` The version of `csvsimple`I have is from July.

Comment: Mine is 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.22)
so i guess its an updated version of latex?

Comment: Has this MacTeX ever been updated? You can see the version of `csvsimple` by looking at the manual you have on disk, run `texdoc csvsimple` in a terminal.

Comment: Remember MacTeX is a snapshot in time. There have been at 600+ updates since MacTeX 2016 was released. You can update to those now, and then where will never be any move updated for MacTeX 2016 (due to the way TeXLive/MacTeX is managed)